# Unable to bind html element to reactive data object in vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am picking up vue3 and tried to build a small functionality where you show your webcam through a click.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <video :src="data.source"></video>
    <button @click="showCamera(data.source)">Turn On Camera</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { reactive, ref } from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "WebCamComponent",
  setup(props) {
    const data = reactive({
      source: document.querySelector("video") as HTMLMediaElement
    });
    const showCamera = (source: HTMLMediaElement) => {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true })
        .then(function (stream) {
          source.srcObject = stream;
          source.onloadedmetadata = e => source.play();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
        });
    };
    return { data, showCamera };
  },
  mounted() { 
    console.log("mounted!");
  }
<script>
...
```

I ran into an issue where `data.source` is null when I click on "Turn On Camera", but I have initialized it to `document.querySelector("video") as HTMLMediaElement`. What am I missing? Also please inform me if I am declaring the type correctly for `reactive()`, or if I should use multiple `ref<SOME_TYPE>()` instead (new to TS).

Comment: Your `data.source` in the template and in `setup` is referencing each other in cycle. That doesn't make too much sense. Also `document.querySelector('video')` will give you null, as the document is not mounted yet in `setup`.

Comment: Oh okay. is there any way to assign `document.querySelector('video')` to `data.source` when the document finishes loading?